# Why files have .js and .jsx (2 different) file extension(s) in React?

Tags: reactjs, file-extension

distinguish files written with JSX from files written in plain js in React.

Comment: @zolty13 thanks for a quick answer.

Comment: Basically it's for human use so that YOU, the human, can easily tell that the file is a JSX file and not a regular javascript file without opening it. For the same reason you can code in JSX and save it as mycode.pdf or mycode.doc and tell React explicitly to compile them but YOU, the human, may confuse them as Adobe pdf files (instead of JSX files) or Microsoft Word files because you look at the file names and make some assumptions.